# MongoDB multi level group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some input data :

```
Brand   | Model   | Number
Peugeot | 208     | 1
Peugeot | 4008    | 2
Renault | Clio    | 3
Renault | Megane  | 4
```

I would like to get both :

- the sum for each brand
- the global sum

Here is my expected output :

```
Brand   | Number
Peugeot | 3
Renault | 7
Total   | 10
```

I think I have to create two `$group` operations and set Total with `$literal`.
What is the right way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said this can be done by 2 group bys, so let's start by putting some data in to mongo similar to your example input:

```
> db.cars.insertMany([
   { "Brand" : "Peugeot", "Model" : "208", "Number": 1 },
   { "Brand" : "Peugeot", "Model" : "4008", "Number": 2 },
   { "Brand" : "Renault", "Model" : "Clio", "Number": 3 },
   { "Brand" : "Renault", "Model" : "Megane", "Number": 4 }
 ]);
```

Now we've got all our cars inserted we can then aggregate these using the 2 group aggregation operators:

```
db.cars.aggregate([
  { $group : { "_id" : "$Brand", "Number" : { $sum : "$Number" }}},
  { $group : { "_id" : null, "Rows" : { $push : { "Brand" : "$$ROOT._id", "Number" : "$Number" } }, "Total" : {$sum : "$Number" } }}

])
```

This will give us the following output

```
{
        "_id" : null,
        "Rows" : [
                {
                        "Brand" : "Renault",
                        "Number" : 7
                },
                {
                        "Brand" : "Peugeot",
                        "Number" : 3
                }
        ],
        "Total" : 10
}
```

We can then clean it up with a projection

```
db.cars.aggregate([
  { "$group" : { "_id" : "$Brand", "Number" : { $sum : "$Number" }}},
  { "$group" : { "_id" : null, "Rows" : { $push : { "Brand" : "$$ROOT._id", "Number" : "$Number" } }, "Total" : {$sum : "$Number" } } },
  { "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "Data" : { "$concatArrays" : [ "$Rows", [ { "Brand": { $literal : "Total" }, "Number" : "$Total" } ] ] } } }
])
```

Giving us the following result

```
{
        "Data" : [
                {
                        "Brand" : "Renault",
                        "Number" : 7
                },
                {
                        "Brand" : "Peugeot",
                        "Number" : 3
                },
                {
                        "Brand" : "Total",
                        "Number" : 10
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: It works but I rather expected someting like that : {
        "_id" : null,
        "Rows" : [
                {
                        "Brand" : "Renault",
                        "Number" : 7
                },
                {
                        "Brand" : "Peugeot",
                        "Number" : 3
                }                {
                        "Brand" : "Total",
                        "Number" : 10
                }
        ]
}

Comment: Great, that was the tick I was looking for ;)